# replace $ in the file content

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

In unix, How to replace $ symbol(only between alphabets) in all the lines in a file?

sample file content

```
abcd$efg
abc$_efg
abc123_$1def
```

sample output should be

```
abcd_efg
abc$_efg
abc123_$1def
```

Comment: `sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]\)\$\([a-zA-Z]\)/\1_\2/'`

Comment: what is that 1_ and 2 denote?

Comment: @vignesh you may want to read this guide: http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html sed - 20 examples to remove / delete characters from a file

Comment: @dawg, you can use `[[:alpha:]]` in place of `[a-zA-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` like so:

```
$ echo 'abcd$efg
abc$_efg
abc123_$1def' | sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)\$\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g'
```

Prints:

```
abcd_efg
abc$_efg
abc123_$1def
```

The `\1` and `\2` replace the characters that border the `$` since `sed` lacks look arounds.